# C++ strings and working with MySQL

Tags: mysql, string, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, c++14

I am having issues passing string variables to MySQL connector. I am using VS2015 and a standard example from MySQL Examples.
The below code works fine

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h> 
#include <cppconn/exception.h> 
#include <cppconn/resultset.h> 
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << endl;
try {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    // Create a connection   

    //string db = "test";
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "user");
    // Connect to the MySQL test database //  
    con->setSchema("test");
    //con->setSchema(db);
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
    while (res->next())
    {
        cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
        // Access column data by alias or column name //    
        cout << res->getString("_message").c_str() << endl;
        cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
        // Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column //    
        cout << res->getString(1).c_str() << endl;

    }
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

However, since I don't want to be hardcoding database schemas in my file, I am trying to use a string variable db and pass it to the MySQL connector as in the below code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "mysql_connection.h"
#include <cppconn/driver.h> 
#include <cppconn/exception.h> 
#include <cppconn/resultset.h> 
#include <cppconn/statement.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

cout << "Running 'SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message'..." << endl;
try {
    sql::Driver *driver;
    sql::Connection *con;
    sql::Statement *stmt;
    sql::ResultSet *res;
    // Create a connection   

    string db = "test";
    driver = get_driver_instance();
    con = driver->connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:3306", "user", "user");
    // Connect to the MySQL test database //  
    //con->setSchema("test");
    con->setSchema(db);
    stmt = con->createStatement();
    res = stmt->executeQuery("SELECT 'Hello World!' AS _message");
    while (res->next())
    {
        cout << "\t... MySQL replies: ";
        // Access column data by alias or column name //    
        cout << res->getString("_message").c_str() << endl;
        cout << "\t... MySQL says it again: ";
        // Access column fata by numeric offset, 1 is the first column //    
        cout << res->getString(1).c_str() << endl;

    }
    delete res;
    delete stmt;
    delete con;
}
catch (sql::SQLException &e) {
    cout << "# ERR: SQLException in " << __FILE__;
    cout << "(" << __FUNCTION__ << ") on line " << __LINE__ << endl;  cout << "# ERR: " << e.what();
    cout << " (MySQL error code: " << e.getErrorCode();
    cout << ", SQLState: " << e.getSQLState() << " )" << endl;
}
getchar();
return 0;
}
```

which fails with an unhandled exception at runtime as

Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFCBA981F28 in Hello World.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: std::bad_alloc at memory location 0x000000F08CAFCDA0.

I can see that MySQL is disconnecting disgracefully hence I am assuming that MySQL is not being able to understand the string passed as schema.

I suspect that the encoding/termination in variable db is different from "test" hence the issue.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The following code change worked.

```
con->setSchema(db.c_str());
```

I guess it was an issue in coversion between std::string and sql::SQLstring.

Thanks